# ImportError: cannot import name 'bytes_type' from 'oauthlib.common'

Tags: python, airflow, authlib, flask-oauthlib

I am updating airflow from 1.10.5 to 1.10.10. I am getting the following error in webserver when using google OAuth

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 37, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 75, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 900, in webserver
    app = cached_app_rbac(None) if settings.RBAC else cached_app(None)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 295, in cached_app
    app, _ = create_app(config, session, testing)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py", line 108, in create_app
    update_perms=conf.getboolean('webserver', 'UPDATE_FAB_PERMS'))
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 202, in init_app
    self.sm = self.security_manager_class(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/security.py", line 177, in __init__
    super(AirflowSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 51, in __init__
    super(SecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py", line 249, in __init__
    from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/client.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .utils import to_bytes
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_oauthlib/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from oauthlib.common import to_unicode, bytes_type
ImportError: cannot import name 'bytes_type' from 'oauthlib.common' (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauthlib/common.py)
```

This error is because of the dependency mismatch. `Airflow 1.10.10` is installing `oauthlib==3.1.0` and `Flask-OAuthlib==0.9.5` and in `3.1.0 version of oauthlib`, there is no bytes_type while Flash-OAuthlib is expecting it to be there.

Considering that [lepture](https://github.com/lepture) has archived [flask-oauthlib](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib) and created [authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib), I see a PR in airflow from lepture about this change https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6140/files but it is not merged and marked stale by the bot

Has anyone faced this issue in Airflow 1.10.10? I have fixed this issue by changing the `oauthlib version to 2.1.0` in [requirement.txt](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt#L195)

Comment: Had the same problem. Using the 1.1.0 version worked for me.

Comment: 1.1.0 version of which dependency? Flash-OAuthlib?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue and temporary fixed it by force upgrade flask_oauthlib to 0.9.6:
(When we wait for airflow fix its dependencies)

`pip install flask_oauthlib==0.9.6`